# how to determine new features when doing feature engineering?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I'm working on a project where I need to build a Neural Network Model to compensate the error that a Vehicle GPS make. my Dataset consists of 4 features: **longitudinal Acceleration, lateral Acceleration, speed and yaw Rate** and my output is the azimuth (angle according to north from the false GPS coordinates to the true GPS coordinates) and distance between the false GPS coordinates the true GPS coordinates. so it's a regression Problem and I thought maybe a Feed Forward Neural Network would perform good in this task but I'm struggling to implement a neural network that can fit my data. My model starts to learn good for the first epochs and then it stucks at a high loss value like it is unable to learn anymore, it even fail to overfit the data, I tried all preprocessing approaches and neural network best practices but that didn't help. My last thoughts were that maybe something is wrong with the data or maybe I need more features to complete such a task so I want to make some feature engineering and that's why I want to ask here how can I make that in my case? I don't know whether it makes sense but I thought maybe I can take the derivative of the acceleration and add that as a features or maybe I can take the square of it or the square of the speed? so I have many Ideas but I'm not sure what to do and how can I have a sense for this so I wish someone here have the experience to help me on this.

PS: I don't have an Error in my NN Implementation because I tried to run my model only on 10 examples of the data and the NN achieved to map the relationship between those 10 examples, it was also good when I used 100-1000 examples but when I take more than 3000 examples, the NN starts to learn and then it get stuck at some high loss value that's the reason why I started to think maybe something is wrong with the data or that I need more features to do this

Comment: I recommend to try it with some ML library, only on comparison purposes.

Comment: @viceriel  can you please explain more, which libraries and how can I use it exactly?

Comment: For example tensorflow. You need to have installed some Python 3.5 and higher. [Install tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), and than design similar topology as yours according [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)

Comment: I'm already using tensroflow and pytorch. that's not what I want to know, the feature engineering have nothing to do with tensorflow or any framework per se

Comment: Yes I read that, but trying it prove, that your implementation of neural network is correct without any doubts.